# help using CWinThread in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

in my project  im having manager class and calc class. calc class derived from CWinThread. and manager have a pointer to calc class. how do i using AfxBeginThread and where?
note im new in mfc so im sorry if there is mistakes.
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [help in MFC threads UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654696/help-in-mfc-threads-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call `Calc::CreateThread()`.  You need to override the `CWinThread::Run()` method to implement your functionality, and you might also want to override the `CWinThread::InitInstance()` and `CWinThread::ExitInstance()` methods too.

Comment: thanks, but i didnt understand where to use AfxBeginThread and how

Comment: You shouldn't have to; you can call Calc::CreateThread() and it will start the thread itself; you don't need to use AfxBeginThread().

Comment: i used Calc::CreateThread() how can i know i new tread has started?

Answer (score 1):

I consider this an MFC tutorial kind of question.

Therefore, let me point you to [www.codeproject.org](http://www.codeproject.com), which is one of the better sites for MFC resources. (Indeed I think there are some really excellent articles and code examples there.)

For example, you can find an intro on MFC threads in the article '[Threads with MFC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/threads_and_mfc.aspx)'.